# Groovy / Gradle / Spock: IncompatibleClassChangeError when running a test

Tags: java, gradle, exception, groovy, spock

I've been struggling with this for the past two days, I went through all kind of forums imaginable but still can't get an answer. I'm getting the following error when running a Spock test:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class java.lang.Class does not implement the requested interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject
```

The problem is I get this error on only 1 of 10 tests, everything else works just fine. The offending test looks like this:

```
class NodeTest extends Specification {

  @Shared
  Configuration config
  @Shared
  Section section1, section2
  @Shared
  Attribute attr1, attr2

  def setupSpec() {
    config = new Configuration("config").tap {
      nodes {
        this.section1 = section("section1") {
          nodes {
            this.section2 = section ("section2") {
              nodes {
                this.attr1 = stringAttribute("attr1") // this is where it fails
                this.attr2 = stringAttribute("attr2")
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  def "Test"() {
    when:
    true

    then:
    config
  }
}
```

It seems that somehow assigning to the `this.attr1` causes the test to fail. Removing the assignment makes it compile fine. Even assigning to a local variable works. But assigning to `this.attr1` is what makes it crash.

I read the problem is probably some incompatible version of Java or Groovy library, but even when running `gradle dependencies` I couldn't see any weird stuff. Everywhere is Groovy 2.5.4.

This is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:2.5.4'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:2.5.4'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:2.5.4'

    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5'

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:2.9.9'
}
```

Here is the list of dependencies from `gradle dependencies`

```
testCompile - Dependencies for source set 'test' (deprecated, use 'testImplementation' instead).
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:2.5.4
|    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:2.5.4
|         \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:2.5.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:2.5.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9.3
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:2.9.9
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9 -> 2.9.9.3 (*)
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
\--- org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:2.5.4 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-nio:2.5.4
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-macro:2.5.4
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:2.5.4 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test:2.5.4
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     |    \--- junit:junit:4.12
     |         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:2.5.4
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:2.5.4 (*)
     \--- junit:junit:4.12 (*)

testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:2.5.4
|    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:2.5.4
|         \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:2.5.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:2.5.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9.3
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:2.9.9
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9 -> 2.9.9.3 (*)
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
\--- org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:2.5.4 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-nio:2.5.4
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-macro:2.5.4
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:2.5.4 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test:2.5.4
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     |    \--- junit:junit:4.12
     |         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:2.5.4
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:2.5.4 (*)
     \--- junit:junit:4.12 (*)

testCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'test'.
No dependencies

testImplementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
No dependencies

testRuntime - Runtime dependencies for source set 'test' (deprecated, use 'testRuntimeOnly' instead).
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:2.5.4
|    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:2.5.4
|         \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:2.5.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:2.5.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9.3
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:2.9.9
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9 -> 2.9.9.3 (*)
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
\--- org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:2.5.4 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-nio:2.5.4
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-macro:2.5.4
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:2.5.4 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test:2.5.4
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     |    \--- junit:junit:4.12
     |         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:2.5.4
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:2.5.4 (*)
     \--- junit:junit:4.12 (*)

testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:2.5.4
|    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:2.5.4
|         \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:2.5.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:2.5.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9.3
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:2.9.9
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9 -> 2.9.9.3 (*)
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
\--- org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:2.5.4 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-nio:2.5.4
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-macro:2.5.4
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:2.5.4 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test:2.5.4
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     |    \--- junit:junit:4.12
     |         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:2.5.4
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.4
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:2.5.4 (*)
     \--- junit:junit:4.12 (*)
```

The Java SDK in Intellij is set to Java 1.8.0_172.

I'm desperate. Do you see anything I'm overlooking? Any ideas where to look next?

Comment: Honestly, I would NEVER do any assignments within builder's body. This is not what they are for and will lead to unpredictable results

Comment: Thank you, I see your point. In practice I wouldn't do that but for the sake of the unit test I did. Anyway, I guess I need to test it some other way, it would be probably easier than figuring this out.

Comment: the thing is, that Spock test itself is based heavily on builders, and if 2 builders interfere...

Comment: I'd recommend to mock the `Configuration` object if possible, to make the testing straight-forward